# Read / Write a USB Stick with STM32F103C8

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, usb-drive

I'm trying to read/write data to a USB flash drive.

I have read in the reference manual that STM32F103xx has a USB peripheral but can only act as a device in the communication. From what I understood, I need it to act as a host. Is there anyway to do this operation without USB to UART converters as I'm trying to be more efficient(in a financial sense).

I seem to find no clue on the internet regarding this particular MCU.
If this can be done only with a UART converter, please show me where to look.

Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, a USB host is required and the STM32F103xx can only assume the device role. A USB to UART converter will not help either. It doesn't implement the flash drive protocol. You'll need to upgrade to another STM32 MCU supporting USB host role.

Comment: You need an USB host which speaks USB Mass Storage protocol. I don't understand why you even bring up UART. Not only is an UART useless when trying to talk to a USB Mass Storage device, but that USB-UART device **also** needs an USB host.

Comment: Thank you both for sparing your time to answer! :D

Comment: F1 series 105/107 series have hardware host support.

Answer (score 1):

As multiple people pointed out, STM32F103C8 can't be a host in the USB communication protocol, therefore the transfer of data cannot be done.

I made a mistake when I thought the USB to UART converter will solve the problem. The converter doesn't have a mass storage protocol implemented on it, therefore it cannot read the data.

See the comments for answers.